# How to make my iOS (iPhone, iCloud) notes available on my Android phone?

Tags: ios, notes

I'm looking for the easiest way to make my iOS (iPhone, iCloud) notes available on my Android phone.

It seems that there's no way to move them to Google Keep, for example.

I'd be fine with using any apps for notes which would allow me to import them from iCloud and put them on my Android phone.

Comment: There is an application on play store called "WiFi file share pro with ios".. I'm not sure but I think you should try this may be it helps... Best.

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides no official way of moving your notes off of iCloud. [Here's their support article on exporting your data off of iCloud](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204055) (hit `Notes`).

However, you can do it with unofficial tools. My method of switching over all of my notes from iCloud Notes and Gmail Notes in the OS X Notes app to Evernote was using [Notes Exporter](http://writeapp.net/notesexporter/) to export all notes to `.txt` files, then dragging each created file over the Evernote app to import. However, if you don't have a Mac, you'll have to use copy and paste (sorry).

---

**Edit**: If your notes are not in iCloud Notes but actually in Gmail Notes (let me know if you can't tell), this [If This Then That recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/23892-ios-notes-sync-to-evernote) might help.

Comment: I'm not a fan of Evernote, but I guess it will have to do for now... I tried going through Gmail but couldn't wait long enough for IFTT to see my notes. So I used the Notes Exporter - thanks!

Comment: @ValentinGolev Glad at least one solution helped!

Comment: omg, I just realized that all my russian text turned into series of question marks: "????? ???????? ????"... I think the Notes Exporter can't work with it. I'll have to look for other options tomorrow.

Comment: @ValentinGolev Awkward. Huh.

Comment: I gave up trying all of the BS answers across the Internet. I use Linux and all of these "convenient" third-party applications aren't even targeted to users like me. I'm pretty sure they're all scams anyway. Anyhow, I couldn't find a solution. In 2020, there still exist none. Evernote can't export to Android easily, the GMail method is broken in iOS 13.3, and iCloud doesn't export to plain text format. Heck, I can't even access "Files" in iOS plugging it into my computer. So, I just used iCloud. I moved all of my notes to iCloud and copied one-by-one into plain text on my computer.